# Mono throws OutOfMemoryException on Ubuntu but not OSX or Windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, .net, c#, mono

I have installed Mono on an Ubuntu server and "Hello World" is working, but a simplified application that does some array handling and runs without problem under Mono on OSX or Windows is giving:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory.
  at (wrapper alloc) object:AllocVector (intptr,intptr)
```

It should not require more than a few MB of memory. The server has 4GB of RAM.

Running again under alloc profile gives a different exception:

```
System.OverflowException: Number overflow.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) object:__icall_wrapper_mono_array_new_specific (intptr,int)
```

The problem is inconsistent, sometimes the code runs once but then not a second time. Sometimes it doesn't work for the first time. Sometimes it fails in a different method but for the same reason.

The program and full output can be downloaded at http://dev.intelorca.co.uk/2014/gacj_allocproblem.zip
It would be good to see if anyone else has problems running the program under mono and can provide any insight on what the problem is. Any pointers to configuring Mono to run better on Ubuntu would also be helpful.

The program should output "Cambridge Surprise Major" 128 times.

Comment: Your mono installation might be broken.

Comment: I first installed it using apt-get install mono-complete and then from the source code, both result in this problem. What part of the installation / configuration could cause this to happen.

Comment: how did you install from source? did you remove mono-complete first before installing from source?

Comment: something like:

wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-3.8.0.tar.bz2

tar -xvf mono-3.8.0.tar.bz2

cd mono-3.8.0/

./configure --prefix=/usr/local

make

sudo make install

I didn't uninstall mono-complete beforehand, but mono --version shows the build date of when I built mono.

Comment: Are you on Arm processor and working with floats/doubles? Try upgrading to 3.12...

Comment: The processor is a Atom™ N2800. Its all integer arithmetic. And it can sometimes run the code once but then not again even though the input is the same.

Comment: Mono 3.12 didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to a bug in Mono's just-in-time compiler with the amd64 architecture. This has been fixed as of 3 Jan 2015.

Bug report: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=25631
Fix: https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/9e03c10d8fefea9210ca015cf484e819623c0a1a